# Resources of project

Tags: c++, winforms, clr

I need to change the PictureBox's image in the file.h, i do it by writing this:

```
mass[oldcord.first - 1, oldcord.second + 1]->Image = Image::FromFile("EMPTY.png");
```

But if i run my project not from the folder, i'll get an error because if can't find the image, because i execute it not from project folder. How can i use "resources" not from my form, but from other files like this:

```
this->MainField->Image = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^>(resources->GetObject(L"Field")));
```

I want my application execute from any place, not only from my folder with project.

I tried to pass form resources through constructors, but I failed

Addition:

```
#pragma once
#include "MainForm.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

enum TYPE { EMPTY, BLACK, WHITE };

ref class Figure
{
public:
    Figure()
    {
        color = EMPTY;
        active = 0;
        king = 0;
    }

    Figure(int x, int y, TYPE color)
    {
        this->color = color;
        this->color = color;
        active = 0;
        king = 0;
    }

    void MoveTo(pair<int,int> newcord, System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^ current, TYPE turn) // ставит на место, меняет статус, цвет
    {
        current->Location = System::Drawing::Point(37 + newcord.second * 90, 37 + newcord.first * 90);
        if (color == EMPTY)
            color = turn;
        else
            color = EMPTY;
    }

    void make_king(System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^% current, int i)
    {
        if (i == 0 && color == WHITE)
        {
            current->Image = Image::FromFile("WhiteKing.png");
            king = true;
        }
        else if (i == 7 && color == BLACK)
        {
            current->Image = Image::FromFile("BlackKing.png");
            king = true;
        }
    }

    bool is_active()
    {
        return active;
    }

    void make_active(bool active)
    {
        this->active = active;
    }

    TYPE getColor()
    {
        return color;
    }

    void setColor(TYPE color)
    {
        this->color = color;
    }

    bool is_king()
    {
        return king;
    }

private:
    Graphics^ picture;
    TYPE color;
    bool active;
    bool king;
};
```

Comment: I am afraid you have edit your question and provide more information! What does ```L"Field"``` mean? it does not look like a valid expression! but then again maybe I am wrong!

Comment: "Field" is an image of game field, which is stored in resources and "Empty.png" is an image which is stored in project folder. And i want use all images from the resources or something else, but only to have an ability to run my project from everywhere, because if i ran it from my desktop, i'm getting error that it can't find my images which are conncted like "Empty" (using image fromfile )

Comment: `this->MainField->Image = gcnew Bitmap(Path::Combine(AppDomain::CurrentDomain->BaseDirectory, "EMPTY.png"));`. The Bitmap must be in your `.exe` path (say, `\x64\Debug`). For the resource objects, see, for example, this: [Accessing embedded resources in C++/CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16760336/7444103).

Comment: Could you explain in more detail? For example of the "cell" class, in the make_king function, I change the picture. I have posted it in addition.

Comment: The C++ IDE never made this easy to do, unlike the C# and VB.NET IDEs, basic assumption is that you would use unmanaged resources like you'd normally do for a C++ app.  If your VS version is old enough then you can still use Project > Properties > Add New Item > Resource > "Assembly Resource File".  If you get the creepy feeling that this is harder than it should be and you probably shouldn't be doing this at all then you'd be right.  Use C++/CLI only for interop with existing C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use boost::program_options for this (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/program_options.html)

For example, your program can have a Config class which holds a configuration options that can change on run time (like a path with resources or whatever you need).

Comment: Well, then may be to parse command-line options? I mean argv[0]. Until you find a better solution..